# Intermittent VBA Run-Time Error 91 in Excel vba with IE

Tags: vba, time

I'm facing Run-Time `Error 91` intermittently when excel VBA code passes value to IEobject.
Say for a set of 15 iterations, I'm encountering error for 3-4 times at same place .

Error is not seen, when I manually (F8) run it. I added delays but in vain.

Acct_name field remains greyed out until currency is fed. 
IE.document.frames("company").document.forms("account").document.all("currency")‌​.Value="USD" IE.document.frames("company").document.forms("account").document.all("currency")‌​.fireevent("onblur")

...delay here

DO while IE.document.frames("company").document.forms("account").document.all.("acct_name‌​").Readystate<>"complete" 'Intermittent run time error 91
 loop

IE.document.frames("company").document.forms("account").document.all("acct_name"‌​).Value= "abc"   'Intermittent run time error 91

Comment: That error would mean the element you're trying to get doesn't exist.  That it runs using F8 suggests a timing problem (is part of the page created dynamically after loading?)  Maybe you can show more of your current code.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies.The page I'm  trying to view has frames, when I enter value in a field through code,it works. But at times I get run time error 91:Object required.

Ex:IE.document.getElementById("account_frame").document. getElementById("account_name").Value = "abc"

In case of error, code breaks and when I manually (F8) run it, the error is not seen. I’ve tried following 
1) adding delays as suggested below by @santhosh.
2) Using “On error resume next”..Even this line appears just above the error line, error is shown.
Pls guide me here.

Comment: Try checking the readyState of the frame containing the document you're trying to access: that is not the same as the readyState of the main page.

Comment: **Update your question if you have code to add** - don't post it as a comment.

Comment: Apologies, added code in the question

Comment: `ReadyState` is a property of the *frame* object, so you need to check `IE.document.frames("company").ReadyState`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Tim its timing problem you may add delay of 5 seconds and see the output.

```
   load:
Do While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5) ' delay of 5 seconds

Set account = IE.document.getElementById("account_name")
If account Is Nothing Then GoTo load
account.Value = "abc"
```